# Why does my Node.js server hang with this small script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

**Edit: Answered below**

New to Node.js here, I really want to know why this script hangs forever when I'm attempting to connect to the created server.

I've had this happen often enough when I'm trying to create a server and I'm not sure why, as it seems to happen with very similar code:

Node script:

```
var http = require("http");
var file = require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    file.readFile("chat.html", "UTF-8", function(error, content)
    {
        if(error) { console.error(error.stack); response.end(); }
        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type" : "text/html"});
        response.end(content);
    });
}).listen(1994, function(){console.log("Listening");});

var websocket = require("socket.io").listen(server);

websocket.sockets.on("connection", function(socket)
{
    socket.emit("message", {"message" : "Hello World"});
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = websocket.connect();

            socket.on("message", function(message)
            {
                console.log(message);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Socket file.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If there is an error then it should end the response and if there isn't it should end the response, or does it have something to do with the web socket?

Comment: When there's an error from `.readFile()` you're not exiting the callback function, though I'm not sure exactly how that would hang the server.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect my current code. Whether I have just `response.end()` by itself or `response.end(); return false;`, neither solve the hanging problem. I suspect it's a problem with the web socket.

Comment: I still think you should `return` when there's an error, but that's probably not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `websocket.connect()`. Socket.io uses `io` as a global object in the front end, not `websocket`. So it should have been `io.connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing how you are invoking `socket.io`:

```
var websocket = require('socket.io')(server);

websocket.on('connection', doStuff);
```

This example follows directly from [the docs on GitHub](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io).